# In a drupal commerce, how to use the same picture for every size attribute

Tags: commerce

I have a dresses drupal commerce. I have 45 dresses in différents colors and size.

My problem is that I have the same picture for every size.

My product variation is composed of a sku,price,color,size,image.

As You can see , I have the image in the product variation. Mean that I need to reselect the image for every color,size variations.

Any Idea on how could I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using commerce feeds, just use the same url to the same image on your server; or manually upload the same image for each!

Comment: Thanks, I'll read about commerce feeds in that case. Anybody know how to create a batch of Product Variation. I would like to have something more faster to manage the product

Comment: Again, feeds let you do bulk product import, so if you want to automate it that's a good way.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Commerce Option](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_option) and [Commerce Product Attributes](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_product_attributes)